# SQL Table Unioning: Array Column

Tags: sql, databricks, union

I am using databricks.

I have `Table 1` which has several columns and an array column.

I have `Table 2` which has the same columns as `Table 1` except for the array column. For `Table 2` the array column is not applicable.

I want to combine these tables but I have been failing so far. I have tried `UNION ALL` but that still gives me an error: `Union can only be performed on tables with the compatible column types.`

I have also tried to populate `null` in the Table2 array column as shown below. This throws the same error.

Is there a solution beyond creating a "fake" array in Table2 so I can perform this union? I was always under the assumption `union all` would exempt the union from data type checks but that's obviously not the case.

```
select
col1,
col2,
arraycol
from table1

union all

select
col1,
col2,
null as arraycol
from table2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try substituting your null value with empty arrays of the specific datatype your array is filled with:

```
select col1,
       col2,
       arraycol
from table1

union all

select col1,
       col2,
       from_json("[]", "array<your_data_type>") as arraycol
from table2
```

Comment: this is a great idea but I keep getting errors like this The 12th column of the second table is struct<id:string,col1:int,col2:int> type which is not compatible with array<int> at same column of first table ... does that mean I have to recreate the exact sequence of data_types in the "fake" arraycol?

Comment: It's difficult to follow up without knowing the nature of the data. Can you update your post with sample data?

Comment: Its verbose and possibly sensitive or else I would have :( I understand if that limits the help

Comment: You can try changing the content and simplifying the structure in the right proportions.